# Calling a function in C++

Tags: c++, function

I'm new to the whole C++ programming thing, and I know this is a easy solution, but I just cant figure it out! 
I simply just wanna call a function that prints out 1 + 4.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int func()
{
    cout << 1 + 4;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int func();
}
```

It shows nothing in the console window, only that the application stopped with return code 0.
Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What are the symptoms?

Comment: remove `int` when calling a function, now it tries to declare a new function instead of calling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not calling `func()` function correctly:

```
int main()
{
    // int func(); This line tries to declare a function which return int type.
    //             it doesn't call func()
    func();   // this line calls func() function, it will ouput 5
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Straight forward! Thanks!

Comment: Or even `return func();`

Comment: Yes, if `func()` is not `void`

Answer (score 1):

you can just call the function by its name. Like func();

```
int func()
{
    cout << 1 + 4;
    return 0;
}
```

the above function is retruning an integer. you are returning 0. to make it more useful return the sum and catch it in main function.

```
int func(){
    return 1+4;// return 5 to main function.
}
```

now in main.

```
int main (){
     int ans = func();// ans will catch the result which is return by the func();
     cout<<ans;
     return 0;
}
```

try to understand the working of each statement.

Comment: Thanks, now if i do this in an If statement, the compiler says "expected primary expression before 'int'".

Comment: @Christoffer do not "extend" questions via comments on answers, if you don't manage to get your if working it's better to create a new question.